# Replace path url placeholder format

Tags: java, regex, apache-commons

What's the best way to replace a path url placeholder. I have the following that needs to be replaced

```
/user/:name/password/:password
```

as

```
/user/{name}/password/{password}
```

Is there a library that could do this for me in Java?

Comment: Us a callback with this regex `(?<=/):([^/]*)`, then in callback, use group 1 as the key to a hash, then replace with it's value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the format is so simple, and : isn't a valid URL character, I would just use a basic regex matching : followed by any word, capturing the word for reprint.

```
"/user/:name/password/:password".replaceAll(":(\\w+)","{$1}")
```

Answer (score 2):

Just using [String#replaceAll](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-) can achieve your way.

```
"/user/:name/password/:password".replaceAll(":(\\w+)","{$1}")
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to use `replaceAll` like this :

```
String str = "/user/:name/password/:password";
String result = str.replaceAll(":(\\w+)", "{$1}");
```

**Output**

```
/user/{name}/password/{password}
```